# VisualStudio 2015でのOpenSSL（libeay32.lib）リンクエラー

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, boost

現在、OpenSSL(1.0.2g)とBoost（1.60）を、TLS1.2でHTTPS通信をするプログラムを作成しています。
開発環境は、Windows10上で動作するVisualStudio2015です。
ビルドは32bit（x86）のリリースモードで行います。
ライブラリとのリンクはすべて静的リンクです。（組み込み先に制約があるため）

ランタイムライブラリは、「マルチスレッド (/MT)」にしています。

以下のようなプログラムです。
（__iob_funcが未定義と言われるためとりあえず__iob_funcを実装してありますが、これは正攻法なのでしょうか）

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/asio.hpp>
#include<boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ip = asio::ip;
using namespace std;
// __iob_func未定義エラー回避のため。
FILE _iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr };
extern "C" FILE * __cdecl __iob_func(void)
{
    return _iob;
}

int main() {
    try {
        asio::io_service io_service;
        ip::tcp::socket sock(io_service);
        // 正しくビルドできるか確認するだけのコードです。
        boost::asio::ssl::context context(io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_client);
        boost::asio::ssl::stream< boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket > ssl_stream(io_service, context);

        ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        ip::tcp::resolver::query query("sourceforge.net", "https");
        ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(*resolver.resolve(query));
        sock.connect(endpoint);

        asio::streambuf request;
        ostream request_ostream(&request);
        request_ostream << "GET /\r\nHost:sourceforge.net\r\n\r\n";
        asio::write(sock, request);

        asio::streambuf buffer;
        boost::system::error_code error;
        asio::read(sock, buffer, asio::transfer_all(), error);
        if (error && error != asio::error::eof)
        {
            std::cout << "receive failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << &buffer << endl;
        }
    }catch (exception& e){
        cout << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

これをVisualStudio2015でビルドすると、リンクエラーが発生します。

```
1>libeay32.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2001: 外部シンボル "__vsnprintf" は未解決です。
1>libeay32.lib(pqueue.obj) : error LNK2001: 外部シンボル "_printf" は未解決です。
1>libeay32.lib(v3_utl.obj) : error LNK2001: 外部シンボル "_sscanf" は未解決です。
1>libeay32.lib(dso_win32.obj) : error LNK2001: 外部シンボル "_sprintf" は未解決です。
```

VS2015のビルドオプションか、OpenSSL側のビルド方法で解決できればいいのですが、
解決方法を教えていただければと。

補足情報ですが、BoostとOpenSSLは下記の方法でビルドしています。

・boost 32bit版

```
b2 toolset=msvc threading=multi variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static address-model=32 --stagedir=stage/x86 -j 8
```

・boost 64bit版

```
b2 toolset=msvc threading=multi variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static address-model=64 --stagedir=stage/x64 -j 8
```

・OpenSSL 32bit版

```
cd c:\openssl\openssl-1.0.2g
perl Configure no-asm --prefix=..\x86 VC-WIN32
ms\do_ms.bat
nmake -f ms\nt.mak install
```

・OpenSSL 64bit版

```
cd c:\openssl\openssl-1.0.2g
perl Configure no-asm --prefix=..\x64 VC-WIN64A
ms\do_win64a.bat
nmake -f ms\nt.mak install
```

回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

外しているかもしれませんが、OpenSSLのビルドオプションがスタティックリンクになっていないのではないでしょうか。
また、OpenSSLをビルドした環境と、現在開発をされている環境でコンパイラのバージョンが違うということはないでしょうか？
上記のような条件でバージョンが違うライブラリを参照した場合、未解決エラーが出ることがあります。

一度OpenSSLを現在の開発環境でビルドしなおしてみてはいかがでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

>OpenSSLをビルドした環境と、現在開発をされている環境でコンパイラのバージョンが違うということはないでしょうか？
>上記のような条件でバージョンが違うライブラリを参照した場合、未解決エラーが出ることがあります。

ドンピシャな回答ありがとうございます。

当方、VS2015のビルドコンソールと勘違いして、
VS2008のビルドコンソールを立ち上げていました。
VS2015のコンソールでビルドしたものをリンクしたところ
未解決エラー解決することを確認しました。

お手数おかけしました。